# inside my string got " result in The string is not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, selenium

i want to use xpath expression to click on the dropdownlist and here is my code.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='LocationInspectionId']/option[text()="+'"3"+"-D-003-1101_01C03"'+"]").click()
```

my option= 3"-D-003-1101_01C03, and i got error:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//select[@name='LocationInspectionId']/option[text()="3"-D-003-1101_01C03"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
> Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: you said that the option is: 3"-D-003-1101_01C03, but the error shows [text()="3"-D-003-1101_01C03"]'.
Can you tell me what's the exact text?

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in the option isn't clear to me if it's 3"-D-003-1101_01C03 or "3"-D-003-1101_01C03" (as it appears in the error).

As per the error it is an incorrect XPATH because the quotes are not closed properly:

```
//select[@name='LocationInspectionId']/option[text()="3"-D-003-1101_01C03"]
```

I am assuming your html might look something similar to this:

```
  <select name="LocationInspectionId">
    <option value="1">"34"-D-003-1101_01C03</option>
    <option value="2">"32"-D-003-1101_01C03</option>
    <option value="3">"3"-D-003-1101_01C03</option>
    <option value="4">"43"-D-003-1101_01C03</option>
    <option value="5">"5"-D-003-1101_01C03</option>
  </select>
```

Now, if you wanted to click on the 3rd option ("3"-D-003-1101_01C03) then you can do this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="LocationInspectionId"]/option[text()=\'"3"-D-003-1101_01C03\']').click()
```

If the option was "3"-"D-003-1101_01C03", then do this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="LocationInspectionId"]/option[text()=\'"3"-"D-003-1101_01C03"\']').click()
```

And for 3"-D-003-1101_01C03:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="LocationInspectionId"]/option[text()=\'3"-D-003-1101_01C03\']').click()
```

If the option is just 3-D-003-1101_01C03, then:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//select[@name="LocationInspectionId"]/option[text()="3-D-003-1101_01C03"]').click()
```

Just make sure you correctly escape (\' or \") the quotes and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your answer solved my problem. I am kind of new to this. actually, i am looking for  3"-D-003-1101_01C03. Thanks again @Shine J